# How can I submit multiple commands to a Python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, sftp

I'm attempting to use a subprocess to interact with some files through sftp.  I can get it to connect and exec one command, but then the process dies.  How can I maintain control over this process and keep moving around in sftp?

---

```
import os
import subprocess

serverFiles = 'sftp.servername.com'
userFiles = 'myusername'
keyfileFiles = 'C:\\key\\file\\path'


with subprocess.Popen(['sftp','-Q','-i',keyfileFiles,userFiles+'@'+serverFiles], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as proc:
    (out, err) = proc.communicate(input='ls -l'.encode())
    print(out.decode())
    #process dies. cannot proc.stdin.write, cannot proc.communicate
```

My output shows me the welcome banner, then the ls from the top level folder, then the process is ended and any following commands error out with `proc` being closed.

Comment: Can you use other python modules for SFTP like paramiko ? 
http://www.paramiko.org/
Also you can write a pexpect script for interactive commands on the shell ?
I dont believe subprocess is the right module to use for interactive shell commands

Comment: My first thought was to use paramiko as well, but there are a few restrictions blocking the way. Namely versioning and managerial aversion to external packages.  Do you have a suggestion outside of subprocess?

Comment: I would have suggested pexpect https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ to create a expect script for interactive shell commands  if pexpect is available

Comment: @cmidi: `pexpect` won't work on Windows (no `pty`). OP could try [`winpexpect`](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home) though It doesn't seem to be maintained.

Comment: That's kind of what I've been finding.  Super old libraries (like paramiko and pysftp) that have badly/not maintained dependencies.

Comment: `paramiko` is actively maintained. https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html) library.  It is designed for SSH and SFTP operations.

Here are a few resources that can show you how to use it:

1. [How do I copy a directory to a remote machine using Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314711/how-do-i-copy-a-directory-to-a-remote-machine-using-fabric)
2. http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/how-to-use-fabric-in-python/
3. [Using Python Fabric without the command-line tool (fab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741523/using-python-fabric-without-the-command-line-tool-fab)
4. [How to set target hosts in Fabric file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326797/how-to-set-target-hosts-in-fabric-file)